# Fetch all facets records against specfic field Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I'm beginner and started learning Lucene. Currently I 've implemented a Count Facets program in lucene 6.0.2 which display or output all facets field count. But now, want to search for a city "California" and in the result it will show all facets count w.r.t this query, How to do this...

Here is the code:

```
public List<FacetResult> runSearch() throws IOException {
    DirectoryReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
    TaxonomyReader taxoReader = new DirectoryTaxonomyReader(taxoDir);
    FacetsConfig config = new FacetsConfig();

    FacetsCollector fc = new FacetsCollector();
    FacetsCollector.search(searcher, new MatchAllDocsQuery(), 10, fc);

    List<FacetResult> results = new ArrayList<>();

    Facets facets = new FastTaxonomyFacetCounts(taxoReader, config, fc);
    results.add(facets.getTopChildren(10, "city"));
    results.add(facets.getTopChildren(10, "make"));
    results.add(facets.getTopChildren(10, "year"));
    results.add(facets.getTopChildren(10, "model"));

    indexReader.close();
    taxoReader.close();

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example I get that you've searched * in your first search. To search for "* AND city:california" (Pretty useless in this case, but works as an example) you can build a DrillDownQuery with your original query and the filter, e.g.

```
Query baseQuery = new MatchAllDocsQuery();
DrillDownQuery ddQuery = new DrillDownQuery(config, baseQuery);
ddQuery.add("city", "california");
FacetsCollector fc = new FacetsCollector();
FacetsCollector.search(searcher, ddQuery, 10, fc);
```

Add can be called multiple times. If you call it for the same field the value is appended with OR, if you call it for a different field those limitation is appended with AND, e.g. (* AND (city:california OR city:york) AND year:1980)